# How do I get the last number from the range() function?

Tags: python, range, fibonacci

Is there a way to get the last number from the `range()` function?
I need to get the last number in a Fibonacci sequence for first 20 terms or should I use a list instead of `range()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are after here but here goes:

```
rangeList = range(0,21)
lastNumber = rangeList[len(rangeList)-1:][0]
```

or:

```
lastNumber = rangeList[-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

by *in a range*, do you mean last value provided by a generator? If so, you can do something like this:

```
def fibonacci(iterations):
    # generate your fibonacci numbers here...


[x for x in fibonacci(20)][-1]
```

That would get you the last generated value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone considered that you need fibonacci numbers. No, you'll have to store each number to build the fibonacci sequence recursively, but there is a formula to get the nth term of the fibonacci sequence.

[Binet's Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html)

If you need the last number of a list, use myList[-1].

Comment: interesante también, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
somerange = range(0,20)
print len(somerange) # if you want 20
print len(somerange)-1 # if you want 19
```

now if you want the number or item contained in a list...

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
print x[len(x)-1]
# OR
print x[-1] # go back 1 element from current index 0, takes you to list end
```

Comment: thanks for answer but with
for i in range(0,21):

print all numbers 0,1,2...
and i need only the last 
20 for the example

Answer (score 0):

Python `range`s are subscriptable and can calculate indices without generating all the numbers:

```
range(1, 10**10, 3)[-1]
```

will return instantly.

The actual computation for `r = range(start, stop, step)` is something like `r.start + (len(r) - 1) * r.step` (`len(r)` is computed in constant time and this assumes `len(r) > 0`)